# How to disable password expiry without chage?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, password

I have an ubuntu linux image, which I use for my single board computer.

When I write it the media (it's an sdcard), then boot and log in, it asks me to change the password.

Since I can mount and modify the sdcard content with another computer before actually performing the boot, I'd like to disable the password expiry.

I know that on a *running* system I can use `chage`, but in this case, the target system is on the card.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man chage`:

> ```
>    -R, --root CHROOT_DIR
>        Apply changes in the CHROOT_DIR directory and use the configuration
>        files from the CHROOT_DIR directory.
> ```

So just `chroot` to the mount point of your sdcard.

Editing `shadow` to delete the expiry times bypasses the normal mechanisms.  It could in principle fail if `shadow` is backed by a database, your `login` reads credential from NIS, and other similar situations, but you probably don't have any of these oddball situations on a sdcard.  So editing `shadow` should work too.

Answer (score 2):

The fields are in `/etc/shadow`.  If you look at them in detail `man 5 shadow`

The easiest way to set an account to have no password aging controls is just to remove all that data

eg

```
username:encrstring:changedday::::::
```

Some systems use 99,999 days as the effective password expiration

eg

```
username:encrstring:changedday:0:99999:7:::
```

In both cases you should not be asked to change the password on next login.